# Injectivity of Borel Functional Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

can anyone explain me why the Borel Functional calculus is NOT injective? And how by using basic measures I can attain $L^\infty$ functional calculus which becomes a $*$-isometric isomorphism ?

Comment: Here's the kicker: $L^\infty$ of what space? $L^\infty(\Bbb R,dx)$, $L^\infty(\sigma(A), dx)$ or $L^\infty(\sigma(A) )$ with another measure $d\mu$, which is special to $A$?